# Bing Map - Using Session IDs to make billable transactions non-billable

Tags: c#, asp.net, maps, bing-maps

Billable transactions can be reduced if session ID is being used for Bing maps.

Details are on this link; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ff859477.aspx

```
You must use the Bing Maps Key that you used to load the map control to request a session ID. This session ID is only valid for the map control session. For the web-based Bing Maps AJAX v7 and Silverlight controls, a session begins with the load of the map into a user’s browser and ends when the browser is closed or the user moves to a different page.
```

I am not sure about **"session ends when the browser is closed or the user moves to a different page"** .

Please correct me if i am wrong, i think on password protected sites session ends when user logs out. For an example; on my asp.net page, first i want to show 20 pin points or locations on one map depends on dataset results and then i want to show may be 10 results on one map. I can save the session id in user session the first time i made the request and use it again and again which will reduce the transactions to 1.

Do i need to use a new session id every time i close the map window? I am thinking about showing map on new window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A map session lasts for as long as the interactive map is loaded. If you navigate to a different page the session is over. Saving the session key to use on other pages is against the terms of use of Bing Maps. The session key is only meant to be used with the services on the same page as the interactive map that created the session key.

You need to create a new session key every time you load a new interactive map.

Comment: if i want to get the travel distance for 60 different coordinates (lat & lng) from one location to other in one go then would it count as 1 trabscation?

Comment: If you want to do that you should break your coordinates into groups of twelve and make multi-point route requests between your points. This will allow you to reduce 60 requests down to 5. You can also use a session key while on the page with these requests to make them non-billable. The loading of the map would generate a billable transactions. That said, it's worth noting that depending on which license you use Bing Maps under there are some restrictions on the number of route calls that can be made, regards less if billable or not.

Comment: there are two different requirements.
Dataset = dataset contains inspectors information including lat and lng. 
On search page, user can either show results in one html table or show all of them on one map with pin points.

What are the restrictions on getting travel distance on multiple addresses? Is it 5 per query or per sec?

Comment: It varies depending on the type of Bing Maps license you have. The limits are usually transactions/year or month, and not per second.